# Adding row_number to concatenated column in data frame pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame like below in `pyspark`

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[(1,'Y','Y',0,0,0,2,'Y','N','Y','Y'),
(2,'N','Y',2,1,2,3,'N','Y','Y','N'),
(3,'Y','N',3,1,0,0,'N','N','N','N'),
(4,'N','Y',5,0,1,0,'N','N','N','Y'),
(5,'Y','N',2,2,0,1,'Y','N','N','Y'),
(6,'Y','Y',0,0,3,6,'Y','N','Y','N'),
(7,'N','N',1,1,3,4,'N','Y','N','Y'),
(8,'Y','Y',1,1,2,0,'Y','Y','N','N')
],
('id', 'compatible', 'product', 'ios', 'pc', 'other', 'devices', 'customer', 'subscriber', 'circle', 'smb')
)
```

Now I want to create a new column `bt_string` in the data frame by concatenating some strings. I have done like below

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
from pyspark.sql import Window

# the below values will change as per requirement
job_id = '123'
sess_id = '99'
batch_id = '1'
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

con_string = job_id + sess_id + batch_id + time_now + '000000000000000'

df1 = df.withColumn('bt_string', f.lit(con_string))
```

Now to the data frame I want to assign a unique number for each row. I applied the `row_number` function like below

```
df2 = df1.withColumn("row_id",f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy()))
```

The output is below

```
df2.show()  

+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+--------------------+------+
| id|compatible|product|ios| pc|other|devices|customer|subscriber|circle|smb|           bt_string|row_id|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+--------------------+------+
|  1|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    0|      2|       Y|         N|     Y|  Y|12399120210301120...|     1|
|  2|         N|      Y|  2|  1|    2|      3|       N|         Y|     Y|  N|12399120210301120...|     2|
|  3|         Y|      N|  3|  1|    0|      0|       N|         N|     N|  N|12399120210301120...|     3|
|  4|         N|      Y|  5|  0|    1|      0|       N|         N|     N|  Y|12399120210301120...|     4|
|  5|         Y|      N|  2|  2|    0|      1|       Y|         N|     N|  Y|12399120210301120...|     5|
|  6|         Y|      Y|  0|  0|    3|      6|       Y|         N|     Y|  N|12399120210301120...|     6|
|  7|         N|      N|  1|  1|    3|      4|       N|         Y|     N|  Y|12399120210301120...|     7|
|  8|         Y|      Y|  1|  1|    2|      0|       Y|         Y|     N|  N|12399120210301120...|     8|
+---+----------+-------+---+---+-----+-------+--------+----------+------+---+--------------------+------+
```

Now I want to add the `row_id` column to the `bt_string` column. I mean like below

if  `bt_string` of `1st` row is

```
1239912021030112091500000000000000 then add the corresponding row_id value. 
In the case of first row the value will be 1239912021030112091500000000000001
```

New column created should have the values like below

```
1239912021030112091500000000000001
1239912021030112091500000000000002
1239912021030112091500000000000003
1239912021030112091500000000000004
1239912021030112091500000000000005
1239912021030112091500000000000006
1239912021030112091500000000000007
1239912021030112091500000000000008
```

Also need to make sure that the length of the column should be always `35` characters.

The below string should not exceed `35` characters length at any cost

```
con_string = job_id + sess_id + batch_id + time_now + '000000000000000'
```

if it exceeds `35` length characters then we need to `trim` the number of `zeros` added in the above statement.

How can I achieve what I want

Comment: Perhaps something like: `df2['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(int(row[bt_string]) + row['row_id'])? That is, convert to an integers, add them, and then convert back to a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to achieve your result

```
# import necessary functions
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
from pyspark.sql import Window

# assign variables as per requirement 
job_id = '123'
sess_id = '99'
batch_id = '1'
time_now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

# Join variables to get desired format of base string
con_string =  job_id + sess_id + batch_id + time_now

# check length of base string and subtract from max length for that column 35 
zero_to_add = 35 - len(con_string)

# Add the numbers of zeros based on the value received above
new_bt_string = con_string + zero_to_add * '0'

# add new column and convert column to decimal and then apply row_number
df1 = df.withColumn('bt_string', f.lit(new_bt_string).cast('decimal(35,0)'))\
    .withColumn("row_id",f.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy()))

# add new column by sum of values from above added columns
df2 = df1.withColumn('bt_id', f.expr('bt_string + row_id'))
```